# How can I fix the duplicate mouse error without logging out?

Tags: ubuntu, mate-desktop

I sometimes get to see something like this:

[image]

When I take a screenshot, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I actually have two mouse cursors + the remainder of a drag-and-drop action on my monitor, but the software thinks it's not there. How can I get back to the "normal" state without logging out?

I have MATE 1.8.2 / Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: What do you mean by 'without logging out'? That just only happen to some random sessions? If yes, then I think that might be a bug. Not related to your question, but are you using `bash`? Can I have your `PS1` pls!

Comment: With "without logging out" I mean that I can fix it when I restart the computer. It happens quite rarely and I am very sure it is a bug. However, I didn't find a bug report... Not related: I use [ZSH + OhMyZSH](http://martin-thoma.com/working-terminal/). I like the git indicator very much :-)